# I don't know why i can't use "datagen.flow_from_directory()"

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

[full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjUtU.png)

[image]

I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are dealing with a problem which has multiple classes, try changing 'binary' to 'categorical' and see if it works. I think there are more than two directories in your train and test folders. When using `flow_from_directory()` each directory inside the parent directory is considered as a different class. Can you post the directory structure? It will become clearer.

Comment: Thank for your answer, sir.
My problem is wrong path, so it cannot catch what i want.
I change it to:`'C:\\Users\\Maya\\.keras\\datasets\\data\\train'`